# Why is my C program continuously run forever without the usage of loop?

Tags: c, infinite-loop, pic, mplab, xc8

I am testing my microcontroller PIC18f4550 with the following circuit on Proteus simulation software.

[image]

My objective is to turn the led on for one second and turn it off.

Following is my code:

```
#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000
void delay(int t);
 
void main(void)
 {
   TRISB = 0x00; // set Port B as output
   LATB = 0x00; // set all 8 outputs on Port B to 0
   delay(20);
   LATB = 1b00000001; // set port B0 to 1
   delay(20);
   LATB = 1b00000000; // set port B0 to 0
    
 }
 
 void delay(int t)
 {
    for (int i=0; i<t ; i++)
    {
       __delay_ms(50); //using xc8 compiler internal delay function - it doesn't like it if delay is too big so it is used inside for loop
    }
 }
```

When the simulation is run, the LED keep blinking forever. I did not use any loop in my program and I only intend to turn the LED on for once. What is causing the LED to blink continuously?

[**EDIT 1**]
I found a solution to my problem. I simply added `while(1){}` at the end of my code to stop the PIC from going into infinite loop.

Comment: It loops within its program memory. It starts to execute from reset vector, then finishes executing your program, then it executes NOPs for all blank program memory addresses or RETLW for once, in case of NOP, PC reaches to the end of the memory: in case of RETLW its stack underflows and causes a device reset, then it restarts (PC = 0) through the reset vector again. You're using hardware loop instead of a software loop :D.

Comment: You may be surprised at the amount of code run by a microcontroller, before it executes `main()` - and that micro probably does not expect you to return from `main()`... doing so will restart the program.

You will probably have a file called cstart.c (or maybe .asm) that you didn't notice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are programming for a microcontrollers. They don't have an extensive OS. Most of the cases, your IDE hides the fact that your main is running in a loop (like Arduino IDE does), or exiting your program makes the microcontroller reset, and will just start the program again.

You labeled it "mplab" , if you check the documentation of it it states:
"*The compiler inserts special code at the end of main() which is executed if this function ends, i.e., a return statement inside main() is executed, or code execution
reaches the main()’s terminating right brace. This special code causes execution to
jump to address 0, the Reset vector for all 8-bit PIC devices. This essentially performs
a software Reset. Note that the state of registers after a software Reset can be different
to that after a hardware Reset.
It is recommended that the main() function does not end.*"

Comment: How do I get around this hardware reset? For instance, what if I want to code my microcontroller to blink once when it is powered up?

Comment: I found a solution by simply adding while loop at the end of my code to stop the program from looping infinitely

Answer (score 1):

The C runtime environment may call `main()` in an endless loop. This can happen deliberately like this:

```c
/* some other stuff... */
for (;;) {
    main();
}
```

Or it can happen because after the return of `main()` the next bytes in the program memory make the processor restart, for example because of an exception, or other code following the call.

You might like to use a simulator that shows the assembly level of your program to follow the flow of control.

Another option is to use your tools to disassemble the executable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the debugger (inside simulator) tool provided in MPLAB X IDE and look how single instructions are being executed. Check if microprocessor is not getting reset by any peripherals.